# XML Parsing with WP8

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse a local XML file that I have in my solution.
I am using the following code:

```
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("Vodka.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> drinkList = xml.Descendants("Drink");

        DrinkGroup data = new DrinkGroup();

        foreach (XElement drink in drinkList)
        {
            data.Items.Add(new Drinks
            {
                name = drink.Element("Name").Value,
                image = drink.Element("Image").Value,
                description = drink.Element("Description").Value,
                ingredients = drink.Element("Ingredients").Value,
                preperation = drink.Element("Preperation").Value
            });
        }

        return data;
```

It works for the first element in drinkList, then returns a System.NullReferenceException.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It seems one of your `Drink` nodes is incomplete (i.e. missing some nodes you assumed it would have). Can you show your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullReferenceException` is *most likely* caused by incomplete structure of some of `Drink` nodes. You can avoid it when you cast element to `string`, as opposed to fetching content via `.Value` property:

```
foreach (XElement drink in drinkList)
{
    data.Items.Add(new Drinks
    {
        name = (string) drink.Element("Name"),
        image = (string) drink.Element("Image"),
        description = (string) drink.Element("Description"),
        ingredients = (string) drink.Element("Ingredients"),
        preperation = (string) drink.Element("Preperation")
    });
}
```